# Проблемы со средой разработки и установкой JDK

Tags: java

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
Добрый день. Прежде чем писать сюда, я основательно по гуглил проблему и всроде бы всё в порядке с настройками, а проблема остается.
Суть проблемы в следующем, переустановил Intellige IDEA, стояла версия 2020, но так как у меня слабый компьютер, то в ней невозможно было работать. Сделал даунгрейд на версию 2016. Эта версия работать стала в разы быстрее на моем железе, однако появилась новая проблема - IDEA перестала видеть установленную jdk.
Я пытался установить путь, она выдает ошибку как на скриншоте. Переустановил джаву, поменял пусть в Параметрах среды (JAVA_HOME - C://program files/Java/JDK14.../; Path - КОРЕНЬ JDK/bin). Удалил весь кэш от переустановленной изначальной мойе версии ИДЕИ. И при добавлении через идею JDK всё так же бьет ошибку как на скриншоте. 
Может быть кто то сможет помочь..

Comment: Может ещё и jdk даунгрейдить

Comment: Думал об этом. Сейчас попробую, только вот врятле оно поможет, раньше у меня вообще стояла первая доступная с офф сайта версия идеи, 2011 или 2013 года. JDK там был подключен самый новый, который и сейчас у меня. Работало нормально.

Answer (score 1):

Перепробовал многое. Помогло только установка JDK 8. Ставил еще версию 11, но тоже не сработало. Почему то работает только на версии 8.